# Html tooltip didn't work in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add tooltip my view php page here the code

```
<div class="container" id="content-slider">
        <div class="row">
     <div id="info">
              <h3><?php echo $FirstName.' '.$LastName; ?></h3>
              <ul  style=" width: 194px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                <li><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets_profile/img/gender.png"><p><?php if($Gender == 1){echo 'Male';}elseif($Gender == 0){ echo 'Female';}?>, </p></li>
                <li id="dd" href="javascript:void(0)" ><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets_profile/img/location.png"><p><?php echo $Location;?></p></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
<script>
$("#info").foreach(function(){
 $(this).find("dd").tooltip({ position: 'right', content: '<span style="color:#fff"><?php echo $Location;?></span>', onShow: function(){
                $(this).tooltip('tip').css({
                backgroundColor: '#666',
                borderColor: '#666'
                });
                } 
        });
});
</script>
```

I need to add tooltip here and this how my view php page look like

[image]

I can't find the error in here can please need quick help here than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your Javascript/jquery

You're trying to find element dd and not the id of your element li.

to find ids on jquery you should add an '#' symbol before the name of your id, it would be something like

```
$("#info").foreach(function(){
    $(this).find("#dd").tooltip({
        //... your code here
    });
});
```

And that will find your li with id=dd

Comment: why use find at all if you know its a fixed id then just do $('#dd').tooltip("this is my tool tip") or if you want it created via some other function/ajax $('#dd').tooltip(function () { // your code here })

Comment: find is not necessary

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that find in this case is not necessary as we're dealing with ids, I was just preserving his code and showing where he did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

why you make a foreach ? 
if you only want add a tooltip

```
$("#dd").tooltip({ position: 'right', content: '<span style="color:#fff"><?php echo $Location;?></span>', onShow: function(){
                $(this).tooltip('tip').css({
                backgroundColor: '#666',
                borderColor: '#666'
                });
                } 
        });
```